# Deal with MAKEFILE_LIST spaces on windows

Tags: windows, makefile

I would like to get the makefiles list in a cross-platform way.

However on Windows, MAKEFILE_LIST doesn't support well spaces (not protected):

```
$(warning MAKEFILE_LIST=$(MAKEFILE_LIST))
```

Give the following result (because the Makefile is included in another):

```
MAKEFILE_LIST= Makefile C:/Program Files/MyApp/Makefile.include
```

The make string operations are not powerful enough to deal with that, and the regular way to get the top Makefile don't work:

```
THIS_MAKEFILE := $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))
```

returns obviously this corrupted result (because *lastword* is based on spaces):

```
THIS_MAKEFILE=Files/MyApp/Makefile.include
```

Any solution to fix that cleanly (meaning using make functions or system commands calls)?

Comment: It seems to be impossible to do without a complex script protecting the spaces cleverly (e.g. A\ B C). It should be based on file existence. And in batch language... => I will try to solve that differently :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic answer is that make does not support filenames with whitespace in them.  Some very limited use can be successful in some very limited situations, if you're willing to do a lot of extra work.  MAKEFILE_LIST is not one of those limited situations.

It's simplest to just treat pathnames containing whitespace as not supported.  Just don't do it.

Comment: I know that, but the users using my compilation tool chain seems not :-)